# Impossible to use classes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

i have 2 files `ProductTableViewCotrollers.swift` and `Product.swift`

I declare a class in `Product.swift` named `Product` and I am trying to initialize and use it in `ProductTableViewCotrollers.swift` with no success.

here are my `ProductTableViewCotrollers.swift`

```
class ProductsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let p1 = Product()
    let p2 = Product()
    let p3 = Product()
    let p4 = Product()
    p1.name = "" 
    //////......
```

and here  `Product.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Product {
    var name: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var cellImage: UIImage?
}
```

Bot files are of the same target `Phones`

and here is the error saying there was no definition
[image]

I am using Xcode `8.3.3 (8E3004b)`
and osx `10.12.6 (16G29)`

Comment: I found that if i put it inside viewDidLoad it works but i wanna understand why @user1000 because this is some static assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property in one of the ViewController lifecycle methods

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let p1 = Product()
let p2 = Product()
let p3 = Product()
let p4 = Product()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

p1.name = ""



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only declare a variable or create an object outside a method in a class. So `let p1 = Product()` is a valid statement outside a method. This is a global variable declaration of a class with initialization. To access of any of the objects of this class you need to access inside a method. So try below in your `viewDidLoad`-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    p1.name = ""
    p2.name = ""


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a property with a closure:

```
let p1 = { let p = Product()
    p.name = ""
    return p
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement inside some function like

```
func printName() {

   print(p1.name)

}
```

Comment: when i put inside viewDidLoad it works but i don't understand why

Comment: You can declare properties at the class scope. It you can't write abitrary code as the class scope.  Code needs to go inside functions.